# Text hover jquery animation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-transitions

I am trying to accomplish a text hover effect for navigation links, where on mouseenter, the text in the link quickly slides up (briefly disappears), the text changes, then slides down. On mouseleave, the original text comes back.

Similar to what the following site navigation links has:

http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB08808B5

This is what I tried, seems to fire more than once on mouseenter and the animation is never carried out as described above:

```
<div class="navbar-right" >
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Cars</a><span class="nav_anim">to drive</span></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Wood</a><span class="nav_anim">to chop</span></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">steak</a><span class="nav_anim">to eat</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
var orig, anim;
$('.link').mouseenter(function () {
    orig = $(this).text();
    anim = $(this).parent().children('.nav_anim').text();
    $(this).stop(true,false).slideUp(300).text(anim).slideDown(300);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop(true,false).slideUp(300).text(orig).slideDown(300);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f0raekme/1/

Comment: why not do it with only CSS? (transitions)

Comment: That site has many effects in it. Your question is not clear. Also, this question will become obsolete if that site dies...

Comment: @TJ edited accordingly.

Comment: *this is what I've tried* - And what's the problem?

Comment: @Jared Farrish, working example described in detail above along with a live example, problem replicated in JS Fiddle. Edited further.

Comment: You've described some behavior, then shown some code. *Nowhere do you say **this is what's wrong, and how do I fix it?*** Read the text yourself.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend, if this is acceptable - i can post it as answer: http://jsfiddle.net/f0raekme/3/, i've simplified things a little, and changed css...

Comment: @Jared Farrish, it is described as clearly as possible, If you can't comprehend it enough to answer, move along, thanks.

Comment: @nevermind, this is exactly what I am looking for, please post it as a solution, so I can accept :) Thank you!

Comment: It should not have been that difficult to get that added to the question.

Comment: So now you're randomly downvoting my questions and answers. What a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("ul li").hover(
    function() {

        first = $(this).children('a.link');


        $(first).animate({
            marginTop: "-20px",
            opacity: '0'

        }, 300);

    },



    function() {

        $(first).animate({
            marginTop: "0px",
            opacity: '1'
        }, 300);

    }



);
```

And, slightly changed css: (fixed height)...

```
li {
    display:block-inline;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid grey;
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f0raekme/3/

Comment: It's be nice if you format the answer... just a suggestion.. :)